# How to do a COUNT with a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I actually have a query joining 3 tables to collect informations so I can calculate some KPIs, but my logic is flawed, here is my actual query :

```
SELECT t.idCustomer, t.nameCustomer
COUNT(DISTINCT t.idTrip), 
SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN t.tripDone <> 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END),
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN t.codeIncident = 'CANCEL'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END)
FROM 
(SELECT customer.idCustomer, customer.nameCustomer, trip.tripDone, incident.codeIncident
FROM CUSTOMER customer
JOIN TRIP trip ON customer.idCustomer = trip.idCustomer
JOIN INCIDENT incident ON trip.idTrip = incident.idTrip) t
GROUP BY t.idCustomer, t.nameCustomer
```

So, I want to know for each Customer :

- COUNT(DISTINCT t.idTrip) -> The number of trips by this customer
- Sum when t.tripDone <> 1 -> The number of trips that are done by this customer ( not ingoing )
- Sum when t.codeIncident = 'CANCEL' -> The number of trips by this customer where there was a cancellation.

The big mistake I made here, is that a trip can have multiple codeIncidents (example : one record for an idTrip with the codeIncident 'CANCEL' and another record with same idTrip with the codeIncident 'DELAYED'), so when I calculate the Sum when t.tripDone <> 1 I get a result of : '2' instead of '1' (because there are 2 records in my from Clause that have the t.tripDone <> 1 for the same idTrip).

Would you have any idea on how I should process this query so I can do the Sum when tripDone <> 1 only once for each tripId ?

Thanks a lot for the help !

If you need some more infos I'm available, and sorry for my lack of english skills !

Comment: Oracle, sorry for no precision

Comment: you need - I think - only the last status of the trip. Try to filter out to have the last status using window functions like row_number.

Comment: what is the value of tripDone when all the codeIncidents are either CANCEL or DELAYED?

Comment: @KaranShah , for my example the value of tripDone when all the codeIncidents are either CANCEL or DELAYED is 0, but it also can be 1

Comment: @lilli when is it 1 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do the same `count(distinct ...)` pattern for the columns you're currently summing, but with some logic. You can use `case` within a count instead in the same way:

```
...
COUNT(
  DISTINCT CASE
    WHEN t.tripDone <> 1
    THEN t.idTrip
    ELSE null
  END),
COUNT(
  DISTINCT CASE 
    WHEN t.codeIncident = 'CANCEL'
    THEN t.idTrip
    ELSE null
   END)
```

The `else null` is a bit redundant as that's the default. As `count()` ignores nulls, if the `when` isn't matched then that trip ID isn't counted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I admire you !

Answer (score 0):

First Select idTrip field in your inner query that means table "t"

Comment: Oh yeah, it was done in the real case but I forgot it when re-wrote it simplier for StackOverflow, my bad !

Comment: @lilli - why use a subquery (inline view)  at all?